# SQL Trigger inserting over 400 records on each insert

Tags: sql, triggers

Im trying to create a trigger which inserts data into a table, from another table which has has also just had data inserted into it, however each tme i add a record in the main table, it adds over 4000 in the other table. Below is my code.

```
USE [TeesdockDB new ]

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[B/WeigherUpdate] ON [dbo].[TBL Combined Board and Reg]
After INSERT AS
   INSERT INTO [TBL B/Weigher](Pronumber,CargoCode,[B/weigher],Tonnes)
   SELECT Pronumber,CargoRef,[B/Weigher],Tonnes
   FROM [TBL Combined Board and Reg]
```

Comment: Please do not use spaces and slashes and special characters in object names as columns...

Comment: You're selecting everything from that table to insert into the other table; if you only want the newly inserted row you'll need a condition to filter the result set down to only that row.

Comment: I'm redesigning an old database, therefore I didn't define the names, however your comments haven't helped the question be solved.

Comment: what is number of records in table [TBL Combined Board and Reg]

Comment: No triggers on the TBL B/Weigher

Comment: As general rule, if you are writing a trigger and **not** referencing either `INSERTED` or `DELETED`, you are doing something wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to filter the rows added add a `WHERE` clause. The `Inserted` table will hold the data inserted, so you may want to use it.

Something like:

```
USE [TeesdockDB new ]

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[B/WeigherUpdate] ON [dbo].[TBL Combined Board and Reg]
After INSERT AS
   INSERT INTO [TBL B/Weigher](Pronumber,CargoCode,[B/weigher],Tonnes)
   SELECT Pronumber,CargoRef,[B/Weigher],Tonnes
   FROM Inserted
```

I know i didn't use `WHERE`, but the `Inserted` table will only have rows affected.

You may also have a look at [Use the inserted and deleted Tables](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx).

Comment: You won by few seconds ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Inserted` table that contains the newly added records.

Here is your update query. But use Where condition to get recently inserted records.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[B/WeigherUpdate] ON [dbo].[TBL Combined Board and Reg]
After INSERT AS
   INSERT INTO [TBL B/Weigher](Pronumber,CargoCode,[B/weigher],Tonnes)
   SELECT Pronumber,CargoRef,[B/Weigher],Tonnes
FROM INSERTED
```

P.S. -  Take care of naming conventions in your table names. :)